# Get the innerText of a p tag when clicking on a button sitting next to it (no Jquery)

Tags: javascript

I have a few boxes that each of them contained button and a `<p>` element that its innerText was create by data from an API.  I put an `onclick` on each box (the `<div>` that wrap the `<p>` element and the button).  I want every time the button is clicked, the `innerText` of the `<p>` tag that is "sitting" next to the this button, in the same div, will console log. Can't figure this out at the moment, this is what I have got so far:

```js
const containerShapes = document.getElementById("container-pock-shape")
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-shape")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data.results.map(item => {
        return containerShapes.innerHTML +=
         `<div class="shape-box" onclick="showName(event)">
            <p>${item.name}</p>
            <button>Select</button>
          </div>`
    }))

function showName(e) {
    console.log()
}
```

```css
#container-pock-shape {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shape-box {
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
    
.shape-box p {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container-pock-shape">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the name, since the event is on the entire div, you need to use `querySelector` and find the inner `<p>` element and grab its text.

```js
const containerShapes = document.getElementById("container-pock-shape")
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-shape")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data.results.map(item =>
    containerShapes.innerHTML +=
      `<div class="shape-box" onclick="showName(this)">
        <p>${item.name}</p>
        <button>Select</button>
      </div>`
  ))

function showName(box) {
  const name = box.querySelector('p').textContent;
  console.log(name);
}
```

```css
#container-pock-shape {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shape-box {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.shape-box p {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container-pock-shape"></div>
</body>
```

An alternative way to do this would be to add the click event to only the button, and look for the `closest` shape box and then locate the `<p>`.

```js
const containerShapes = document.getElementById("container-pock-shape")
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-shape")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data.results.map(item =>
    containerShapes.innerHTML +=
      `<div class="shape-box">
        <p>${item.name}</p>
        <button onclick="showName(this)">Select</button>
      </div>`
  ))

function showName(button) {
  const name = button.closest('.shape-box').querySelector('p').textContent;
  console.log(name);
}
```

```css
#container-pock-shape {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shape-box {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.shape-box p {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container-pock-shape"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use closest. Also never use map when you need forEach or use map correctly

I also strongly suggest delegation (grab click on the div)

```js
const containerShapes = document.getElementById("container-pock-shape")
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-shape")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => containerShapes.innerHTML = data.results
    .map(({name}) => `<div class="shape-box">
      <p>${name}</p>
        <button>Select</button>
    </div>`));

containerShapes.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button")
  if (tgt) console.log(tgt.closest("div.shape-box").querySelector("p").innerText)
})
```

```css
#container-pock-shape {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shape-box {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.shape-box p {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container-pock-shape"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution for this problem. (Of course if your text is not too long like a button text) you can give your inner text as an id to element, and in event handler you can access your inner text this way: `e.target.id`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35503265)